# Editing excel query to work well with powerbi query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have excel report that needs to be made in powerbi. Now I have 1 more problem with the last query.
In excel there is a sheet "Lists" that contains all kinds of random data ( for ex. document paths, calculated dates etc, theyre all pretty randomly ).

In query I have line:

```
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each Cube.AttributeMemberId([#"Date - Time.Year"]) = Text.Combine({"[Time].[Time].[Calendar Year].&[", Number.ToText(Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end])),"]"}) meta [DisplayName = Number.ToText(Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end]))]),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Date - Time.Days", type date}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each [#"Date - Time.Days"] >= #date(Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{5}[start]),Date.Month(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{5}[start]),Date.Day(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{5}[start])) and [#"Date - Time.Days"] <= #date(Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end]),Date.Month(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end]),Date.Day(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end]))),
```

In that code first row part:

```
Number.ToText(Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end]))
```

I've figured out this code connects to the excel file sheet "Lists" ( table from A1 to F7) - something like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| NameOfSource |   httpaddress    |   start    |    end     |      Path       |   File   |
+--------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| Data 1       | http:....        | 09.03.2020 | 11.03.2020 | http:....       |          |
| Data 2       | http:....        |            |            | http:....       |          |
| Data 3       | X:\....\.. .txt  |            |            | X:\....\.. .txt |          |
| Data 4       | X:\....\.. 2.txt |            |            | X:\....\.. .txt |          |
| Data 5       | X:\....\.. 3.txt | 01.03.2020 | 08.03.2020 | X:\....\.. .txt | xxx.json |
+--------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

So my guess is the code part `[Content]{0}` refers to the `end` column where value is `11.03.2020`.
Now this `11.03.2020` is calculated with code `=DATE(YEAR(NOW());MONTH(NOW());DAY(NOW())-1)`.

In PowerBI I do not want to use this method how to fetch data, if possible I  want this data into the original query code somehow.
So instead of `Number.ToText(Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{0}[end]))` I'd like the code to do the same calculations without pointing to another sheet or place.

Same with

```
Date.Year(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{5}[start])
```

Instead of pointing to a sheet row `[Content]{5}[start]` here uses code `=EOMONTH([@end];-1)+1`

Hope I explained well enough :)

OR since this is not the only data queries pull from this "Lists" sheet, maybe it is easier to create such a sheet in powerbi aswell? In that case is there any documentation that would explain how to do this? Because I don't think PowerBI uses `(Excel.CurrentWorkbook)` or something like that.

Comment: If you're asking how to do calcs inside power bi, the answer is most likely DAX.

Comment: Are you just asking how to get yesterday's date or start of month inside powerquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power query M language has very nice [built-in date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-functions).

Instead of `DATE(YEAR(NOW());MONTH(NOW());DAY(NOW())-1)`, you can write

```
Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1)
```

Instead of `EOMONTH([@end];-1)+1`, you can write

```
Date.StartOfMonth(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```

It might be cleaner if you first define today's date as

`Today = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())`

and then write

```
Date.AddDays(Today,-1)

Date.StartOfMonth(Today)
```